# Mocking psycopg2 - how do I raise the exception?

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, mocking, psycopg2

I'm trying to handle potential execution problems with psycopg2 database. IIRC `psycopg2.DatabaseError` should handle most sql errors. The method inserts a `html` string into `full_html` column inside `mytable` and returns the `id` associated with it.

```
def insertPage(cursor, html):
    try:
       cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO mytable (full_html)"
        "VALUES (%s) RETURNING id"), (html,))
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError:
         print("error inserting html")
```

and the test:

```
def test_insertPage_error(self):
    mockPage = (1, 'html') # Row contains id and html string

    with patch('psycopg2.connect') as mock_connect:
        with self.assertRaises(psycopg2.DatabaseError):
            mock_cur = mock_connect.return_value.cursor.return_value
            mock_cur.fetchone.return_value = mockPage

            resultId = insertPage(mock_cur, 'html')
```

I'm having trouble invoking the `psycopg2.DatabaseError`. I've tried replacing `'html'` argument with None or another value that's not a string. I'm thinking it's a problem with my `mock_cur` not returning what I want? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the error i'm raising?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/tests/testInsert.py", line 62, in test_insertPage_error
    resultId = insertPage(mock_cur, 'html')
AssertionError: DatabaseError not raised
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `insertPage()` function is already catching the `psycopg2.DatabaseError` and printing a message instead, and exiting without raising another exception. That's why the `DatabaseError` never makes it out of the `insertPage` function.

Try changing your `insertPage` function to just make the `cursor.execute` call, without the try/except block, which will allow `insertPage` to pass the exception up the chain instead of catching it:

```
def insertPage(cursor, html):
   cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO mytable (full_html)"
        "VALUES (%s) RETURNING id"), (html,))
```

Alternatively, you could define a custom exception type and raise it when you encounter the `DatabaseError`:

```
class SpecialDatabaseError(Exception):
    pass

def insertPage(cursor, html):
    try:
       cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO mytable (full_html)"
        "VALUES (%s) RETURNING id"), (html,))
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError:
        raise SpecialDatabaseError("This is a special error!")
```

then your mock would assert that the `SpecialDatabaseError` is raised:

```
   with self.assertRaises(SpecialDatabaseError):
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually had a custom exception class but I didn't think to raise it.  Now to encounter a DatabaseError (thereby raising the SpecialDatabaseError) what could be done to trigger it?

Comment: You can call `cursor.execute()` in a way that will cause a `DatabaseError` - and there are many ways that can happen. Or you can just put a `raise psycopg2.DatabaseError()` on the line after `cursor.execute()`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Alternatively, you could also mock `cursor.execute` to raise an exception using `MagicMock.side_effect`

Comment: Thanks - I was asking more about inside the test itself, but yes the MagicMock.side_effect is something I'll try.